# Python: How to efficiently catch "duplicates" in a list, then run a comparison between them?

Tags: performance, list, python-2.7, compare, grouping

I've gone through previous posts, and there are many comments on some of those posts about complexity, while other comments  say certain solutions don't work for Python 2.7. So I hope this isn't a duplicate.

I have a very long list, that resembles something like this

```
my_list = ['Elephant 300', 'Giraffe 900', 'Monkey 84', 'Elephant 298', 'Tiger  428',...]
```

I need my code to catch `'Elephant 300'` and `'Elephant 298'`, then compare the trailing number, and eliminate the lower one, so that the list then only contains `'Elephant 300'`.

How can I do this while being efficient (and hopefully not overly complex)?

Comment: You are looking at a hard solution because you state your problem wrong. The data structure you choose is the wrong tool to make the comparison - so you need to choose a better fitting data structure, e. g. a list of tuples, dictionaries ec. And may take a look at the article "tidy data" - it is written for data scientists but (with a little abstraction) useful for everybody

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dictionary in which the keys are "Elephant", "Giraffe", etc., and the values are numbers.  The number stored for a given animal will be the largest number seen so far for that animal. You will iterate through the list, split each string into animal and number, then compare the number to the one stored for that animal in the dictionary.  If the new number is greater, you will replace the old number with the new number.
When this is all done, you will go through the key,value pairs in the dictionary, create new strings, and put them in a list.
This is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following:

```
d = {}
for item in list_of_animals:
    k,v = item.split()
    if not k in d:
        d[k] = int(v) #store value at name of animal
    else:
        if int(v) > d[k]:
            d[k] = int(v) #higher number becomes new value for animal name

#put values back in list
l = ['='.join((k, str(v))) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place for `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in [i.split() for i in my_list]:
    if d[k] < v:
        d[k] = v
my_new_list = [' '.join([str(k),str(d[k])]) for k in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['Elephant 300', 'Giraffe 900', 'Monkey 84', 'Elephant 298', 'Tiger  428']
my_dict = {}

for item in my_list:
    key, value = item.split()
    if key in my_dict.keys():
        stored_val = my_dict[key]
        if float(stored_val) < float(value):
            my_dict[key] = value
    else:
        my_dict[key] = value

print my_dict

 #If you want a list back
my_new_list = [key+' '+my_dict[key] for key in my_dict.keys()]
print my_new_list
```

Output:

{'Tiger': '428', 'Giraffe': '900', 'Monkey': '84', 'Elephant': '300'}

['Tiger 428', 'Giraffe 900', 'Monkey 84', 'Elephant 300']

Note: you can also store multiple values for a particular key in my_dict and then eliminate the lower one. I chose to compare the values and store only the larger value. Hope it helps!